# How to avoid nested map for better rendering performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this nested map that kind render slow after redirection I tried to map only the group and it was really fast, any idea how to get rid of this nesting yet achieve the same results? also could calling the function inside of return causing this dip.....

```js
itemSet =  [
      { id: 1, group: 'A', item : 'someitem' },
      { id: 2, group: 'A',  item : 'someitem' },
      { id: 3, group: 'B',  item : 'someitem' },
      { id: 4, group: 'B', item : 'someitem' },
    ]

const groupItems = (items) =>
  items.reduce((group, items) => {
    if (!group[items.group]) {
      group[items.group] = [];
    }
    group[items.group].push(items);
    return group;
  }, {});

const items = (item) =>
    Object.entries(groupItems(item)).map(([group, items]) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <group name={group} />
        {items.map((item) => (
          <item
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            item={item.item}
          />
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={themeDark}>
      <AppBar />
      <CssBaseline />
      {items(itemSet)}
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your usecase is to render the array of array grouped by `group`. You will have to use the nested loops but you're missing `key` attribute in the first map. Try adding `key` there in the `React.Fragment`.

```js
const items = (item) =>
    Object.entries(groupItems(item)).map(([group, items]) => (
      <React.Fragment key={group}>
        <group name={group} />
        {items.map((item) => (
          <item
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            item={item.item}
          />
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={themeDark}>
      <AppBar />
      <CssBaseline />
      {items(itemSet)}
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
```

Working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-dust-uxq5c?file=/index.js)

Comment: you think this is causing the dip ? tbh i tried it kind of improved...

Comment: Yep, That's one reason and there is one more. You're not using 2 loops but 3 including the `Object.entries`. Can put a working codesandbox example. I can check and help you there with a number of loops.

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vibrant-sky-jwrmf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) kinda similar

Comment: Updated the example. https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-dust-uxq5c?file=/index.js

Not a fan of `for...in` but that is reducing one loop in here.